# Spninner's getItemAtPosition method not working

Tags: android

I'm not using any adapter. I have the position of items of a spinner. Not I have to get the string from the Item at the particular position. Its not selected item though. How can i get the item from the position value of item I have?

```
`package com.wordpress.ishansaysjava.advisingscheduler;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CourseListActivity extends Activity {

    Button course1 ;
    Button course2 ;
    Button course3 ;
    Button course4 ;
    Button course5 ;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_course_list);

        course1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.course1);
        course2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.course2);
        course3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.course3);
        course4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.course4);
        course5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.course5);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        course1.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("course1", "ADD A COURSE"));
        course2.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("course2", "ADD A COURSE"));
        course3.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("course3", "ADD A COURSE"));
        course4.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("course4", "ADD A COURSE"));
        course5.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("course5", "ADD A COURSE"));
    }

    public void addCourse (View view)
    {
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Spinner class_time = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.class_time);
        Spinner lab_time = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.lab_time);

        if(view.getId() == R.id.course1)
        {
            if(course1.getText().toString().equals("ADD A COURSE"))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddCourseActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("list_pos", R.id.course1);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            else
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, CourseActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("class_time", class_time.getItemAtPosition(sharedPreferences.getInt("class1", 0)).toString());
                Log.i("classtime", (String)class_time.getItemAtPosition(3));
                intent.putExtra("lab_time", lab_time.getItemAtPosition(sharedPreferences.getInt("lab1", 0)).toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        if(view.getId() == R.id.course2)
        {
            if(course2.getText().toString().equals("ADD A COURSE"))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddCourseActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("list_pos", R.id.course2);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            else
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, CourseActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        if(view.getId() == R.id.course3)
        {
            if(course3.getText().toString().equals("ADD A COURSE"))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddCourseActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("list_pos", R.id.course3);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            else
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, CourseActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        if(view.getId() == R.id.course4)
        {
            if(course4.getText().toString().equals("ADD A COURSE"))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddCourseActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("list_pos", R.id.course4);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            else
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, CourseActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        if(view.getId() == R.id.course5)
        {
            if(course5.getText().toString().equals("ADD A COURSE"))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddCourseActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("list_pos", R.id.course5);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            else
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, CourseActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }


}
`
```

Comment: what do you mean by getItemAtPosition method not working? what it returns?

Comment: For example:Log.i("classtime", (String)class_time.getItemAtPosition(3)); Here classtime is a spinner but i can't get the item by this method but i should get it :/

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried so far and the error message that it is throwing. Then may be we can help you out.

Comment: Post code you have tried for spinner.

Comment: there is a code snippit....I'm new here..can't post the whole code :(

Comment: I have given my code @jaydroider

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in `sharedPreferences.getInt("lab1", 0)` inside spinner.getItemtAtPosition() function.

Try to debug the app and check what integer value it is returning or set the value obtained from `sharedPreferences.getInt("lab1", 0)` in log and check logcat.

Comment: Its returning the proper value Sir :/

Comment: Post ur xml file how u hv defined Spinner and its entries in string.xml file, Hv u taken 'string-array' for defining entries in string.xml?